# Array implementation of a Queue

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, queue

My professor gave us a quiz about array implementation of a queue and one of the questions was the following:

**After many enqueue, dequeue operations would your queue lose access to the array?  How many?  Why?**

**My answer is the following:** One of the drawbacks of using array implementation of a queue is that the size of the array is fixed. We need know the number of elements that will go in to a queue before-hand. As we run the enqueue and dequeue operations, we will be wasting lot of spaces in the array and after some time, we will lose access to the array because we will eventually run of out space in the array. The space issue is easily avoided if we use a circular array based implementation of a queue.

I am not sure whether I answered this question correctly or not. But how do we know that how much space will be wasted? **Please help!**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the real question here. It seems this question is mostly "backstory," telling about a question on a quiz (which you answered, and it doesn't look like you've gotten any feedback that your answer is wrong). Can you edit it down to just the relevant bits of the question? Otherwise it's hard to know what you're looking for exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using static length arrays, you'd have to stop queue operations after LEN consecutive enqueues, or stop dequeue operations after LEN consecutive dequeues.

LEN is the constant number for the length of your array.

If you're using dynamic arrays, you won't have that problem at all.

Making it circular won't help at all.

Comment: Java doesn't have anything called a "dynamic array."

Comment: Then he won't be using one, will he?

Comment: I am wondering   Why wouldn’t this happen if you were implementing pop for a Stack?

Comment: That's true, but it's as helpful as pointing out that you won't have that problem if you code while sitting on a unicorn.

Comment: @yshavit I think it's quite obvious that this question doesn't ask for a code. It's a basic data structure question. OP can use whatever s/he gains from my answer to give a java specific answer if he wants to

Comment: @mallumamu Why it wouldn't happen? But it would happen. If you run out of things to pop, you would have to stop dequeueing.

If you run out of space, then you would have to stop enqueueing.

Comment: @mallumamu If you used a circular structure on top of a constant length array, you can circle from the end to the beginning but there are still finite many slots. If you meant to ask why making it circular won't help, that's why.